# Text Overlapping on Email Signature from iPhone to Gmail.com

Tags: ios, html-table, gmail, html-email

When I send my email signature from an iPhone and view it at gmail.com the text starts overlapping. I have checked all settings on the phone and all text size etc is defaulted. I don't have any line-height anywhere and after I paste I am shaking the phone to 'undo' to stop picking up the default character attributes. By removing sections of text I managed to isolate that the top table is causing the problem - if I remove that it works, but then my text doesn't sit side-by-side with the image.

Anyone see anything else i've missed? Have spent hours and feel like i'm hitting a brick wall.

```
<body>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="200" width="550" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><tr><td style="border-right: solid 1px #c1c1c1; padding-right: 0px; display: block; clear: both;"><a href="https://www.url.com"><img src="https://url.com/portfolio.jpg" width="133px" height="200px"></a></td>
<td style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0;">

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><tr><td colspan="2" style="padding-bottom: 0px; color: #221f1f; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold;"><img src="https://www.url.com/emailsig/logo.png" width="250px"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 5px; color: #221f1f; font-size: 21px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold;">Name Here</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" style="padding-bottom: 2px; color: #70bcc9; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">Title</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #545454; font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom: 3px;"><span style="color: #9eb333; font-weight:bold;">&#9658; </span><a href="https://mywebsite.com/" style=" color: #545454; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 13px; text-decoration: none;">mywebsite.com</a></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #545454; font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><span style="color: #9eb333; font-weight:bold;">&#9658;</span> <a href="tel:408-508-6789" style=" color: #545454; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 13px; text-decoration: none;">555-555-5555</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: #9eb333; font-weight:bold;">&#9658;</span> <a href="tel:831-525-5000" style=" color: #545454; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 13px; text-decoration: none;">555-555-5555</a></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #545454; font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-bottom: 7px;">Location</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #9eb333; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="https://www.myurl.com/emailsig/tw-facebook.png" width="18px" height="18px"></a>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src="https://www.myurl.com/emailsig/tw-instagram.png" width="18px" height="18px"></a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="https://www.myurl.com/emailsig/tw-youtube.png" width="18px" height="18px"></a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/"><img src="https://www.myurl.com/emailsig/tw-linkedin.png" width="18px" height="18px"></a><span style="display: inline-block;">&nbsp;&nbsp; &#187; JOIN OUR <a href="http://myurl.com" style=" color: #9eb333; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: underline;">MAILING LIST</a></span></td></td></tr>

</table>
</td></tr></table>

<p style="color: #545454; font-size: 10px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top:0px;">Confidentiality text to go here.</p>

</body>
```

Edited to include screenshot of how it looks (the confidentiality text is overlapping)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting line heights on all of your text? It could be that your text is inheriting the default, set by the mailbox.

Comment: You need to check your closing tags, lot of TDs are not closed.. also, you dont need colspan="2" in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one? I have just corrected a few errors

```
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="200" width="550" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-right: solid 1px #c1c1c1; padding-right: 0px; display: block; clear: both;"><a href="https://www.url.com"><img src="https://url.com/portfolio.jpg" width="133px"
                    height="200px"></a></td>
        <td style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0;">

            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; color: #221f1f; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold;">
                        <img src="https://www.url.com/emailsig/logo.png" width="250px"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 5px; color: #221f1f; font-size: 21px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold;">
                        Name Here</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-bottom: 2px; color: #70bcc9; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">
                        Title</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #545454; font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom: 3px;">
                        <span style="color: #9eb333; font-weight:bold;">&#9658; </span><a href="https://mywebsite.com/" style=" color: #545454; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 13px; text-decoration: none;">mywebsite.com</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #545454; font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                        <span style="color: #9eb333; font-weight:bold;">&#9658;</span> <a href="tel:408-508-6789" style=" color: #545454; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 13px; text-decoration: none;">555-555-5555</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <span style="color: #9eb333; font-weight:bold;">&#9658;</span> <a href="tel:831-525-5000" style=" color: #545454; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 13px; text-decoration: none;">555-555-5555</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #545454; font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-bottom: 7px;">
                        Location</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #9eb333; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img
                                src="https://www.myurl.com/emailsig/tw-facebook.png" width="18px" height="18px"></a>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img
                                src="https://www.myurl.com/emailsig/tw-instagram.png" width="18px"
                                height="18px"></a>
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="https://www.myurl.com/emailsig/tw-youtube.png"
                                width="18px" height="18px"></a>
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/"><img src="https://www.myurl.com/emailsig/tw-linkedin.png" width="18px" height="18px"></a>
                        <br> <br>
                        <span style="display: inline-block;">&nbsp;&nbsp; &#187; JOIN OUR
                            <a href="http://myurl.com" style=" color: #9eb333; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: underline;">MAILING LIST</a></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p style="color: #545454; font-size: 10px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top:0px;">
    Confidentiality text to go here.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply / do this. Unfortunately it's still overlapped though :(

Comment: I added a screenshot to show how it's overlapping. It's the bottom section (confidentiality text) that overlaps.

Comment: dont use divs in html email, but if you really want to then try adding <p style="float: none; clear:both">Confi... 
Its the float that makes things overlap

Comment: I don't have any divs?

Comment: Oh im sorry, I mixed to cases together. Try to wrap your Confidentiality in another table->tr->td, then it shouldnt overlap, or maybe just set style="display:block" on the P tag

Answer (score 0):

As well as the fixes Rasmus has made to the code, this seems to be an issue on send/forward.

What happens if you place the confidentiality text in it's own 100% table?

Comment: Good thinking, but unfortunately it still does the same.